# PDFBox : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 1-based index not found: 2 error in getPage()

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox version : 2.0.27

The pdf file has 55 pages which loads perfectly in every application

while parsing the pdf when call pdDocument.getPage(0) it returns the pdPage object
but when i call pdDocument.getPage(1) it throws the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 1-based index not found: 2
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree.get(PDPageTree.java:342)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree.get(PDPageTree.java:258)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.getPage(PDDocument.java:1547)
```

The pdDocument can load only one page for this file it can not load the other pages of file.

Please refer the code snippet below.

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load("filePath", MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
for(int i = 0; i < pdDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
   PDPage page = pdDocument.getPage(i); //error occurring in this statement
   // rest of the logic
}
```

Please check the below stacktrace which is received in PDFDebugger app

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 1-based index not found: 2
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree.get(PDPageTree.java:342)
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree.get(PDPageTree.java:258)
    org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.ui.DocumentEntry.getPage(DocumentEntry.java:47)
    org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.ui.PDFTreeModel.getChild(PDFTreeModel.java:143)
    java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.PDFDebugger.initTree(PDFDebugger.java:1502)
    org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.PDFDebugger.readPDFFile(PDFDebugger.java:1432)
    org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.PDFDebugger.openMenuItemActionPerformed(PDFDebugger.java:759)
    org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.PDFDebugger.access$400(PDFDebugger.java:141)
    org.apache.pdfbox.debugger.PDFDebugger$4.actionPerformed(PDFDebugger.java:395)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
```

Found below logs in debugger app if it is helpful for troubleshoot.

```
 Info  [PDFDebugger] Parsed in 240 ms
 Warning  [PDPageTree] COSDictionary expected, but got null
 Warning  [PDPageTree] COSDictionary expected, but got null
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please share the PDF for analysis.

Comment: Hi @mkl Thank you for the response. I can not share the pdf because of security reasons.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, I see no way helping you.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr As I checked in PDFDebugger the same error was shown in every version which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I had attached the debugger stacktrace in question.

Comment: That sounds like there is some invalid entry in the page tree of the PDF. @AbhayPatel are you knowledgeable enough in PDF details to check the structure of the page tree of the document manually?

Comment: Look for /Pages in the PDF (open with NOTEPAD++), compare it with a working PDF.

Comment: You can't really "resolve" this issue, the creator of the PDF made a mistake or the PDF was corrupted in transfer. At most, you could save the "repaired" PDF from Adobe Reader and then use that one.

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr as checked in adobe reader we are able to open the same file in Adobe properly there are no errors showing in opening that file in adobe reader.

Comment: I meant save that one with "Save As" so you get a new file. This might then be a repaired file. Btw Adobe opening the file doesn't imply it is correct. Adobe does a lot of quiet repairing when needed.